# VB.net SQL Syntax error

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Can anyone help me with this SQL syntax error? What should I use near the select statement

My code:

```vb
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If Len(Trim(TextBox1.Text)) = 0 Then
        MsgBox("Please Enter Current Odometer For Specified Vehicle", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error")
        TextBox1.Focus()
    Else
        Dim time As DateTime = DateTimePicker1.Value.Date
        Dim format As String = "yy-MM-dd"
        Dim newdate = time.ToString(format)

        Dim SQLStatement As String = "IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM services_list WHERE vehicle_id='" & Label7.Text & "' AND service='" & ComboBox1.Text & "') BEGIN UPDATE services_list Set service_date='" & newdate & "', note='" & RichTextBox1.Text & "', odometer='" & TextBox1.Text & "' WHERE vehicle_id='" & Label7.Text & "' AND service='" & ComboBox1.Text & "' End Else BEGIN INSERT INTO services_list(vehicle_id,service,service_date,note,odometer,milesorkm) VALUES('" & Label7.Text & "', '" & ComboBox1.Text & "', '" & newdate & "', '" & RichTextBox1.Text & "', '" & TextBox1.Text & "', '" & Label8.Text & "') END"

        Dim Query2 As String = "Select * from customers_cars where vin_number='" & ComboBox3.Text & "'"
        Dim cmd As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(Query2, MySqlConn)

        Reader = cmd.ExecuteReader

        Try
            While Reader.Read()
                Dim lastod = Reader.GetInt32("last_visit_odometer").ToString
                Label9.Text = lastod

                If TextBox1.Text <= Label9.Text Then
                    MsgBox("Incorrect Odometer")
                Else
                    Reader.Dispose()

                    cmd.CommandText = SQLStatement
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                    cmd.Connection = MySqlConn
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    MsgBox("Successfully Added!")
                End If

                Reader.Dispose()
            End While
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You forgot to post the error message.

Comment: the error is (you have an error in your sql syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL servcer version for the right syntax to use near"IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM services_list WHERE vehicle_id='" & Label7.Text & "' AND service='" & ComboBox1.Text & "') at line 1)

Comment: There are several possible issues here, therefore post the value of `SQLStatement` before it is assigned to `cmd.CommandText = ` to narrow it down.

Comment: I don't think you can do what you want this way. I think you can use a first (`SELECT`) query, then check it (by `vb.net` code) and finally do the `INSERT` or not. Another way could be a `stored procedure`.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to write it is the so called 'UPSERT' statement in MySql.
(I am not sure but this is T-SQL syntax and it is not supported as is by MySql).
There is instead a standard way (for MySql) to do it

```
INSERT INTO services_list
      (col1, col2, col3)
VALUES
      (value1, value2, value3)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
      col1 = value1
```

Said that, you should switch ASAP to a parameterized query approach. Concatenating string as you do now is two times wrong.
First your code is vulnerable to Sql Injections, second, a simple single quote inside one of your values could wreak havoc with the resulting text creating another syntax error in parsing (not to mention parsing incompatibilities with dates and decimal separators). So use a parameterized query instead.

```
' Create the UPSERT query '
Dim SQLStatement As String = "INSERT INTO services_list " & _
                             "(vehicle_id,service,service_date,note,odometer,milesorkm) " & _
                             "VALUES(@id,@service,@date,@note,@odo,@mile) " & _
                             "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE " & _ 
                             "vehicle_id = @id, service = @service,service_date = @date, " & _ 
                             "note = @note,odometer=@odo,milesorkm = @mile" 
Dim Query2 As String = "Select last_visit_odometer from customers_cars where vin_number=@vinNumb"
Using cmd = New MySqlCommand(Query2, MySqlConn)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@vinNumb", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ComboBox3.Text

    ' You want just one value, so you could avoid the DataReader and all'
    ' the problems connected to a multiple use of the same connection'
    ' using a simpler ExecuteScalar'
    Dim result = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
    If result IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim lastod = Convert.ToInt32(result)
        Label9.Text = lastod.Text
        ' Numbers should be checked against numbers. '
        ' Comparing numerically a string agains another string is a conceptual error'
        If Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text) <= lastod Then
            MsgBox("Incorrect Odometer")
        Else
            ' Now fill the command with the parameters required by the main query'
            cmd.Parameters.Clear()
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = label7.Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@service", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ComboBox1.Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@date", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = newdate
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@note", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = RichTextBox1.Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@odo", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@mile", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Label8.Text
            cmd.CommandText = SQLStatement
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            Dim recs = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            If recs > 0 Then
                MessageBox.Show("Record added or updated successfully!")
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Using
```

Notice that I have used for every parameter a MySqlDbType.VarChar but I am pretty sure that some of your columns want a specific type. Please use the appropriate MySqlDbType for your table (Int32, DateTime etc...)

Comment: steve your code is working but it inserts data only it doesnt update you used 'ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE' but i dont have any unique value in my table, i can't use any uniques because i will use 2 same services like 'Engine Oil' or 'Brake Pads' for two different vehicles.

Comment: But unique keys can also be composed of two (or more) fields like your service and vehicle_id. Does this combination makes the record unique? Can you add another field in the unique key structure? If not you could think to another approach like adding an AUTO_NUMBER column. I really hate working with tables that don't have unique Keys unless there is a precise reason.